# How to remove required to an element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem to remove required to an element using jQuery.

For example below coding, I want to remove `required` in the class, but jquery is doesn't work:

```html
<div class="form-group" id="hidden_other" style="display:none;">
<input class="form-control required"  id="other_model" name="other_model" title="Other Model" placeholder="Please fill in other model">
</div>
```

`jquery`

```html
$("#other_model").removeAttr("required");
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have `required` as an attribute, as in `<input required id="id">` - you have it as a class, so you would use `$("#other_model").removeClass("required")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `removeClass(class)` method, not the `removeAttr(attr)` method. This should do the trick:

```
$("#other_model").removeClass("required")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are having required as a class, so, you should use below code

```
$('#other_model').removeClass('required');
```

if you use required as a property, just like below

```
<input class="form-control"  id="other_model" name="other_model" title="Other 
 Model" placeholder="Please fill in other model"  required>
```

This will make input compulsory, to remove this u should use below code.

```
$('#other_model').prop('required',false);
```

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add the `required` attribute before you can move it.

Here is an example of removing it from an input.

```js
const field = $('#test');
console.log('Is Required', !!field.attr('required'));

field.removeAttr('required');

console.log('Is Required', !!field.attr('required'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" required="true" />
```

Conversely, if you're just trying to remove the `class` `required`, you can simply do `$.removeClass('required');`